# Upload de arquivo não envia

Tags: php

Estou tentando fazer o upload de arquivo, mas não envia para a pasta. Mostra todo o processo de envio do arquivo, recebe no banco de dados o novo nome do arquivo, mas o arquivo não chega na pasta do servidor.

```
<?php
if ((isset($_POST["form"])) && ($_POST['form'] == "form1")) {

  $ext = strtolower(substr($_FILES['arquivo']['name'],-4)); //Pegando extensão do arquivo
  $arquivo = "file_".date('dmYhis') . $ext; //Definindo um novo nome para o arquivo
  $dir = __DIR__.'/uploads/aulas/'; //Diretório para uploads
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $dir.$arquivo); //Fazer upload do arquivo

}
?>


  <form id="form" method="post" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Arquivo (.zip .rar .pdf)</label>
          <input name="arquivo" type="file" id="file-1" required />
        </div>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" id="button" name="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right"><i class="icon-save bigger-110"></i> Salvar</button>
  </form>
```

**ATUALIZAÇÃO 1:**

Fiz o teste em outro servidor e funcionou. O que será que pode ser?

**Atualização 2:**

Ao colocar um `echo '<pre>';print_r($_FILES);echo '</pre>';` para ver a saída, e fica assim:

```
Array
(
    [arquivo] => Array
        (
            [name] => artes-i---eja.pdf
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 1
            [size] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: Já verificou as permissões da pasta?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Sim

Comment: Faz um favor. Eu sei que o pessoal não gosta muito de fazer isso em php mas coloque seu código dentro de `try` para ver se dá para extrair alguma informação.

Comment: Nunca usei o `try`, como devo fazer?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.exceptions.php

Comment: @AugustoVasques eu fiz e não retornou nenhum valor.

Comment: @AugustoVasques parece que é algo no servidor, algo que esteja bloqueando, pois no servidor cPanel funciona em outro servidor que usa outro painel, não funciona.

Comment: Agora que eu vi `[error] => 1`, seu arquivo excedeu o tamanho fixado na diretiva `upload_max_filesize` dentro do `php.ini`

Comment: @AugustoVasques mas no meu arquivo php.ini esta com 12M `upload_max_filesize=12M`.  Esse php.ini esta na pasta root `public_html/`, o onde a ação esta acontecendo é dentro da pasta `public_html/sistema/` , preciso colocar um outro php.ini dentro da pasta sistema?

Comment: Esse não é o caminho convencional para `php.ini`.

Comment: A hospedagem permite criar php.ini personalizado

Comment: Personalizado não significa que reconheça todos os campos. Eu acredito que seja um limite de tamanho interno deles, entre em contado com o suporte e passe essas informações a eles.

Comment: @AugustoVasques erra exatamente isso. Da sua resposta para eu colocar pontuação para você. Valeu!

Comment: Obrigado, só em ter ajudado eu fico feliz. Agora se você ficou grato quiser entrar no meu perfil e ler as respostas que escrevi e caso alguma você ache util e queira a pontuar ficarei lisonjeado.

Answer (score 1):

Verifique as seguintes diretivas das configurações do PHP (php.ini):

- upload_max_filesize - Define o tamanho máximo dos arquivos em um POST.
- post_max_size - Define o tamanho máximo do post (incluindo o tamanho dos arquivos).

Verifique se o primeiro arquivo php que é acessado pelo usuário / webserver tem as permissões necessárias na pasta de upload.

Além disso recomendo que faça algumas alterações para evitar problemas futuros ao utilizar seu script:

```
<?php
function uploadFile($file){

$resultado['ok'] = true;
$formatos = ['pdf', 'zip', 'rar'];
$tamanhoMaximo = 10 * (1024*1024); //10MB
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
//Contem o caractere usado no endereço do arquivo para separar os diretórios no SO atual

$dir = __DIR__."{$ds}uploads{$ds}aulas{$ds}";


$x = explode('.', $file['name']); 
//Quebra a string a cada . e retorna um array
//documento.pdf
//['documento', 'pdf']

$ext = strtolower(end($x)); //Retorna o ultimo valor no array

if(!in_array($ext, $formatos)){
    //Verifica se a extensão NÃO está no array de formatos
    $resultado['ok'] = false;
    $resultado['msg'] = 'O formato do arquivo não é aceito';
    return $resultado;
}

if($file['size'] > $tamanhoMaximo){
    $resultado['ok'] = false;
    $resultado['msg'] = 'Seu arquivo excede o tamanho máximo (10MB)';
}


$arquivo = uniqid('file_') . $ext;
//uniqid retorna o prefixo especificado (file_) seguido por uma ID de 13 caracteres baseado no milionésimo de segundo atual.

$check = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $dir.$arquivo);
if(!check){
    //Verifica se a operação para mover o arquivo NÃO foi bem sucedida
    $resultado['ok'] = false;
    $resultado['msg'] = 'Houve um erro ao fazer o upload';
}

return $resultado;

}


if ((isset($_POST["form"])) && ($_POST['form'] == "form1")) {
    $upload = uploadFile($_FILES['arquivo']);
    if(!$upload['ok']{
        //Se $upload['ok'] NÃO for true
        echo 'ERRO: ' . $upload['msg'];
    }
}

?>
```